# Retirar elemento de uma lista encadeada

Tags: c, lista, alocação, lista-encadeada

Estou implementando uma lista encadeada do tipo "com cabeça". Segue struct referente à lista e a criação dela na main()

```
struct lista{
    int info;
    struct lista *prox;
};
typedef struct lista Lista;


int main ()
{
    Lista *l, *aux;

    l = (Lista*) malloc(sizeof(Lista));

    l->prox = NULL;

    //Trechos de código

    retira_n(l, n);
}
```

Logo a seguir segue a função que retira todas as ocorrências de um dado número "n" da lista e retorna a lista

```
Lista* retira_n(Lista *l, int n)
{
    Lista *atual, *ant, *atual2;
    int flag = 0;

    atual = l->prox;
    ant = l->prox;

    while(atual != NULL)
    {
        if(atual == l->prox && atual->info == n)
        {
            l->prox = atual->prox;
            free(atual);
            atual = l->prox;
            flag++;
            continue;
        }
        else if(atual->info == n)
        {
            ant->prox = atual->prox;
            flag++;
        }

        ant = atual;
        atual = atual->prox;
    }

    if(flag == 0)
    {
        printf("O elemento nao esta na lista");
    }

    return l->prox;
}
```

A função está funcionando de forma parcial, isto é, os elementos da lista não são mostrados quando eu vou "printar" a lista, entretanto por não ter conseguido arrumar um jeito de desalocar a memória com a função free(), pois se eu for desalocar utilizando o ponteiro "atual", por exemplo, não vou poder usá-lo em outras iterações para verificar os outros elementos da lista. Queria uma forma de desalocar o elemento que eu quero excluir e não apenas fazer o anterior apontar para o próximo elemento da lista.

Comment: Se eu entendi bem você tem um problema que não é tão simples de resolver um C. Você tem que controlar o tempo de vida de um elemento que pode ter várias referências. Provavelmente teria que criar um contador de referências (e não permitir referências cíclicas ou ter como usar uma referência fraca). Acho que você não tem ideia do que estou falando. Isto mostre que é um problema complexo demais para atacar em um exercício, a não ser que o exercício seja avançado mesmo e a intenção seja justamente aplicar o *reference counting*. Tem técnicas mais avançadas ainda.

Answer (score 2):

Seu código estáconfuso em alguns aspectos - mas para responder o que você quer, basta re-escrever o segundo if assim:

```
    else if(atual->info == n)
    {
        ant->prox = atual->prox;
        free(atual);
        atual = ant->prox;
        flag++;
    } else {
         ant->prox = atual;
         atual = atual->prox;
    }
```

Perceba que muda também para só avançar o "ant" se o nṍ atual não foi removido  - as linhas fora do `if` que mudam `ant` e `atual` não devem ser executadas caso o nó tenha sido removido (o `ant` permance o mesmo e o `atual` avança).

Dica: evite usar uam variável com nome "l"  - é um símbolo difícil de distinguir de "1". Outra dica: sua variável é um contador ou é um flag - se for um contador, evite chama-lo de "flag".

Comment: Não, mais em baixo no código ele reposiciona ambos ponteiros, desse jeito vai pular a verificação de um nó.

Comment: Obrigado @DaviAragao - corrigido.

Comment: Esse  atual = atual->prox; é necessário?

Comment: Sim - sem ele o laço todo vai ficar sempre no mesmo nó, e não vai percorrer a lista.

Answer (score 2):

Criando um ponteiro adicional e fazendo com que o mesmo aponte para a posição de `atual` antes de `atual` receber o próximo você isola o endereço de memória para ser liberado, aí pode usar o `free` normalmente.

```
Lista* retira_n(Lista *l, int n)
{
    Lista *atual, *ant, *atual2, *morto;
    int flag = 0;

    atual = l->prox;
    ant = l->prox;

    while(atual != NULL)
    {
        if(atual == l->prox && atual->info == n)
        {
            l->prox = atual->prox;
            morto = atual;
            atual = atual->prox;
            flag++;

        }
        else if(atual->info == n)
        {
            ant->prox = atual->prox;
            morto = atual;
            atual = atual->prox;
            flag++;
        }
        else
        {
            ant = atual;
            atual = atual->prox;
        }
        free(morto);
    }

    if(flag == 0)
    {
        printf("O elemento nao esta na lista");
    }

    return l->prox;
}
```